# Enfity Framework Core : unable to translate a group by query with a left outer join

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I'm completely stuck on this simple query, made with Entity Framework Core 6 that should return a list of questions, counting the number of answers for each of them (it's like a forum...):

```
questions = from q in context.ExpertsForumQuestions
            join a in context.ExpertsForumAnswers on q.ExpertsForumQuestionId equals a.ExpertsForumQuestionId into ja
            from a in ja.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join ui in context.UserInfos on q.UserInfoId equals ui.UserInfoId
            where q.Languageid == languageId
            group q by new { q, ui } into g
            select new QuestionListItem
                   {
                       ExpertsForumQuestionId = g.Key.q.ExpertsForumQuestionId,
                       Title = g.Key.q.Title,
                       FirstNameSubmitter = g.Key.ui.FirstName,
                       LastNameSubmitter = g.Key.ui.LastName,
                       Categories = g.Key.q.Categories,
                       NumberOfAnswers = g.Count()
                   };
```

EF Core cannot translate it, returning this error message:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .LeftJoin(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: e => e.ExpertsForumQuestionId,
> innerKeySelector: e0 => e0.ExpertsForumQuestionId,
> resultSelector: (e, e0) => new TransparentIdentifier<ExpertsForumQuestion, ExpertsForumAnswer>(
> Outer = e,
> Inner = e0
> ))
> .Join(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: ti => ti.Outer.UserInfoId,
> innerKeySelector: u => u.UserInfoId,
> resultSelector: (ti, u) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<ExpertsForumQuestion, ExpertsForumAnswer>, UserInfo>(
> Outer = ti,
> Inner = u
> ))
> .GroupBy(ti0 => new {
> q = ti0.Outer.Outer,
> ui = ti0.Inner
> })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Why can it not be translated?

I hope it doesn't fall under the issue reported here
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19813

otherwise, EF Core guys... we are still in an alpha version of the product!

Comment: Specify Grouping key explicitly with all needed properties. `g.Key.q.ExpertsForumQuestionId` is not translatable.

Comment: And probably `g.Key.q.Categories` also not translatable if it is collection.